# SQL WHERE (conditions) AND (condition1 OR condition2) doesn't work

Tags: sql

I have an SQL statement that should return rows if they belong to a certain user and as long as their condition1 is not 1 OR condition2 is not 1. But when I execute it with condition1 or condition2 being 1 only - the row is still returned. I'm trying to make it so if condition1 OR condition2 or both are 1 then don't return such rows, but for some reason it works only if both conditions = 1

```
Select * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.user = $user 
AND (condition1 = 0 OR condition2 = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are contradictory. Here are some solutions for each of them:

> belong to a certain user and as long as their condition1 is not 1 OR
>   condition2 is not 1

If condition1 and condition2 are not nullable:

```
Select * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.user = $user 
AND (condition1 <> 1 OR condition2 <> 1)
```

If they are:

```
Select * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.user = $user 
AND (condition1 <> 1 OR condition2 <> 1 
    OR condition1 IS NULL OR condition2 IS NULL)
```

> if condition1 OR condition2 or both are 1 then don't return

Not nullable:

```
Select * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.user = $user 
AND condition1 <> 1 AND condition2 <> 1
```

Nullable:

```
Select * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.user = $user 
AND ((condition1 <> 1 OR condition1 IS NULL) 
    AND (condition2 <> 1 OR condition2 IS NULL))
```

Comment: condition1 <> 1 **AND** condition2 <> 1 worked. Thanks, I'll mark as answer in 5 min.

Comment: Didn't see your answer before posting; deleted mine and upvoting this.

Answer (score 1):

You got your logic a bit backwards, try this:

```
Select * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.user = $user 
AND NOT (condition1 = 0 OR condition2 = 0)
```